# PyTorch Dataset leaking memory with basic I/O operation

Tags: pytorch, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I am iterating over a `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` with its associated `torch.utils.data.Dataset`. I notice when changing one line in the `__getitem__` method for the dataset, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 10666) is killed by signal: Bus error. It is possible that dataloader's workers are out of shared memory. Please try to raise your shared memory limit.
ERROR: Unexpected bus error encountered in worker. This might be caused by insufficient shared memory (shm).
```

The `__getitem__` looks like this before:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    datafilename = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.labelfile.iloc[idx,2])

    X = np.loadtxt(datafilename, delimiter=',', dtype=np.int32)

    X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float)
    return X
```

and like this after:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    datafilename = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.labelfile.iloc[idx,2])

    with open(datafilename, 'r') as f:
        X = [int(x) for x in f.readline().split(',')]

    X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float)
    return X
```

I am running with the VSCode debugger if that makes any difference. This behavior is persistent even when `num_workers=1` and I have tried on two separate machines with the same error. I believe this not due to hardware, but maybe a memory leak. Also the second version is about 7x faster so I would prefer using that version.

Comment: Which pytorch version are you using?
Have you tried with num_workers=0?

Comment: @Deusy94 pytorch version 1.10.2. I'll try setting num_workers = 0, but this slows down the fetching a bit so ultimately I want to be multihreaded. I have considered reading all the data at once inside the constructor and removing the I/O calls from `__getitem__`, but I am not sure if this is recommended.

Comment: This seems to be due to appending the iteration elements to an external list, causing the memory footprint to increase.

Comment: @Kevin how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @Mazen Removed the external list I was appending to, it was innate to much data to be stored in a list.

Answer (score -2):

It is not a memory leak. Instead, It is a feature of Python. You may encounter this problem when using native Python structures like map or list. There is a **NEW TOOL** called `cstl` ( https://github.com/fuzihaofzh/cstl ). It wraps C++ STL containers to solve this issue. It supports multiple types including nested map, list, and set which the numpy and pytorch do not support.
Here is a simple example showing how it solves the problem:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
import torch
import copy
import sys
import cstl
from tqdm.auto import tqdm


class DataIter(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        cnt = 24000000
        self.cnt = cnt
        #self.data = np.array([x for x in range(cnt)]) # Good
        #self.data = [x for x in range(cnt)] #Leaky
        #self.data = cstl.MapIntInt({i : i for i in range(24000000)})# Good
        self.data = cstl.VecInt(range(24000000)) # Good

        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.cnt

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data = self.data[idx]
        data = np.array([int(data)], dtype=np.int64)
        return torch.tensor(data)

train_data = DataIter()
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=300,
                          shuffle=True,
                          drop_last=True,
                          pin_memory=False,
                          num_workers=18)

for i, item in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader)):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(i)
```